# Unable to ssh into server with some IPs but hosts.deny etc seem okay

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, fail2ban

we have a server and several workstations with fixed IPs. The server is configured to basically deny all ssh requests except for those that are entered in hosts.allow. Here is the configuration.

**hosts.deny**

```
sshd: ALL
```

**hosts.allow**

```
sshd: 192.168.28.38, 192.168.28.182, 192.168.28.120 #and so on
```

However, only some of the entered IPs can log in via SSH *(e.g. 192.168.28.182)*. Other IPs that are also *in hosts.allow* *(e.g. 192.168.28.38)* cannot log in and see the error message `"kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"`

`sudo service sshd status` outputs the following:

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-01-18 21:41:00 CET; 26min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 171575 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 171576 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9257)
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─171576 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Jan 18 21:41:00 nas3 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jan 18 21:41:00 nas3 sshd[171576]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 1636.
Jan 18 21:41:00 nas3 sshd[171576]: Server listening on :: port 1636.
Jan 18 21:41:00 nas3 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jan 18 21:41:02 nas3 sshd[171587]: refused connect from 2003:cf:2732:be00:5dab:2f56:ef10:5536 (2003:cf:2732:be00:5dab:2f56:ef10:5536)
```

Where the IPv6 address belongs to the network interface of the affected workstation.

**fail2ban.log** says this.

```
2022-01-16 22:30:48,213 fail2ban.filter         [2016]: INFO    Added logfile: '/var/log/auth.log' (pos = 193935, hash = e5c5bbd4fbfd8258434cad02588f1651f1bb8cb1)
2022-01-16 22:30:48,264 fail2ban.jail           [2016]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
2022-01-17 17:36:58,043 fail2ban.filter         [2016]: INFO    [sshd] Found 2003:cf:2739:ba00:75f3:6b2a:1f36:c465 - 2022-01-17 17:36:58
2022-01-17 20:53:20,133 fail2ban.filter         [2016]: INFO    [sshd] Found 2003:cf:2739:ba00:75f3:6b2a:1f36:c465 - 2022-01-17 20:53:20
2022-01-18 18:11:49,169 fail2ban.filter         [2016]: INFO    [sshd] Found 2003:cf:2732:be00:2879:c81c:c30:4483 - 2022-01-18 18:11:49
2022-01-18 21:12:10,519 fail2ban.filter         [2016]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.168.28.33 - 2022-01-18 21:12:10
2022-01-18 21:40:24,794 fail2ban.filter         [2016]: INFO    [sshd] Found 2003:cf:2732:be00:5dab:2f56:ef10:5536 - 2022-01-18 21:40:24
2022-01-18 21:41:03,159 fail2ban.filter         [2016]: INFO    [sshd] Found 2003:cf:2732:be00:5dab:2f56:ef10:5536 - 2022-01-18 21:41:02
```

The error exists only since a few days. Before that everything worked, so it doesn't seem to be a fundamental problem.

EDIT (new logs):

**verbose ssh output of failig workstation (using Ethernet):**

```
ssh config@nas3 -p 1636 -v

OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to nas3 [2003:cf:2732:be00::161] port 1636.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

It seems that all workstations that use Ethernet also automatically use IPv6. These cannot connect. All WiFi connected devices use IPv4 and can connect.

Would the solution be to simply add the IPv6 addresses to hosts.allow?
However, I would like to know what could have caused that suddenly only IPv6 is used over Ethernet.

Where can I find more logs or does anyone already know what our error is?

Thanks already for your answers!

Comment: See if the clients that can't connect are trying to connect through IPv6. Or try running ssh with the "-v" flag to print verbose output, then add the output to your question.

Comment: Yes, it seems like all workstations that are connected via ethernet are using IPv6 and all those using WiFi are using IPv4.

Comment: Would the solution be to simply add the IPv6 addresses to the hosts.allow file?
However, I would like to know what could have caused that Ethernet is suddenly only using IPv6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've indicated, the "nas3" hostname apparently resolves to addresses for both IPv4 and IPv6. Some of your clients are trying to connect through IPv6 and being blocked, because your *hosts.allow* file only permits certain IPv4 addresses.

The `ssh` utility has options to force it to use IPv4 or IPv6. You can force IPv4 on the command line:

```
ssh -4 config@nas3 -p 1636
    ^^--- Force IPv4, or -6 to force IPv6
```

Or you can [specify it](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#AddressFamily) in your *.ssh/config* configuration file:

```
Host nas3
    AddressFamily inet       # or "inet6" for IPv6
```

Alternately, you could edit your *hosts.allow* file to [permit IPv6 addresses](https://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.allow):

> An expression of the form '[n:n:n:n:n:n:n:n]/m' is interpreted as a '[net]/prefixlen' pair. An IPv6 host address is matched if 'prefixlen' bits of 'net' is equal to the 'prefixlen' bits of the address. For example, the [net]/prefixlen pattern '[3ffe:505:2:1::]/64' matches every address in the range '3ffe:505:2:1::' through '3ffe:505:2:1:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff'.

If you don't specify address family, `ssh` may use either protocol and it may try IPv6 first. I spent some time looking through the ssh source code, but I wasn't able to determine what controls that. It may be controlled by the operating system. Your WIFI hosts may be connecting through IPv4 because their WIFI network interface doesn't have an IPv6 address assigned to it.